# Bluetooth Dongle for Pi

Tags: bluetooth

I need to do below things with Pi :-

1. Convert to Bluetooth Keyboard
2. Need to pair with my smartphone to Reject all Call and accept only whitelisted call.

I am sure I need to use HID and HFP profiles but problem is selection of compatible Bluetooth USB dongle.

I came across few usb as below :

1. http://plugable.com/products/usb-bt4le
   Remarks: Support HID and HFP .Few threads says that Broadcom chips are bad for Pi
2. [CSR 4.0](http://www.amazon.in/Ultra-Mini-Bluetooth-CSR-Dongle-Adapter/dp/B0117H7GZ6/ref=pd_cp_147_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=1TXM6ASY7PSCZDFZ1HZ5) 
   Remarks: Cannot identify which all profiles are there. I need a help here to identify which all profile are supported.

Please help me .Advance thanks

Comment: Be careful with Bluetooth keyboards, I've had numerous problems with stuck keys and others.

Comment: I turned by Pi to  Bluetooth keyboard . Works on Android and iPhone . 

Next mission to do :

2. Need to pair with my smartphone to Reject all Call and accept only whitelisted call.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were talking about using a Bluetooth keyboard for your Pi, my bad.

Comment: No. I made Pi as Keyboard. Here , Pi is loaded with HID Device profile .

Answer (score 1):

The [Plugable USB Bluetooth Dongle](http://plugable.com/products/usb-bt4le) (Plugable support team doesn't know this .I had once contacted them to know feasibility but they gave a negative response ) works to turn Pi as Keyboard. I installed BlueZ 5 and load HID profile with help Python package called pybluez .It worked.